# Cannot center my span in firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a menu with some Jquery effects and it is working well across all browsers except Firefox (my last menu item is not centered) and i have no idea why is this happening...
It looks like this in Firefox:http://robertpeic.com/future%20net/problem/problem.png                          In other browsers it renders fine:http://robertpeic.com/future%20net/problem/other.png
To solve this I did tried : added fixed width and height to my last anchor tag (***fail***), tried to add margin instead of padding (***fail***), tried to use Firefox hack via CSS it worked but breakes my CSS validation(***fail***),tried to increase padding a little bit and it looked OK in Firefox but breaked in every other browser(***fail***).

My last resort is to use browser sniffing but I **really don't want to use this** for such a small issue. 
Can someone help me to solve this problem?

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QKaGK/)

CSS code :

```
.menu{
position:relative;
display:block;
margin:0px auto;
height:37px;
background:url(http://robertpeic.com/future%20net/template%20images/menu-bg.png);
width:959px;

}


.menu ul{
list-style-type:none;
display:block;
width:990px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.menu ul li a{
float:left;
color:#4e4e4e;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
display:table-cell;
position:relative;
height:37px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url(http://robertpeic.com/future%20net/template%20images/main-menu-divider.png) 100% 0%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:100;
padding:0px 18px 0px 18px;
line-height:37px;
text-align:left;
margin-left:2px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
float:left;
color:#780C71;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
display:table-cell;
position:relative;
height:37px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url(http://robertpeic.com/future%20net/template%20images/main-menu-divider.png) 100% 0%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:100;
padding:0px 18px 0px 18px;
line-height:38px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:2px;
}

.mainhover{
background-color:#BFC0C1;
z-index:50;
position:absolute;
border-radius:5px;
moz-border-radius:5px;
border-top: 1px solid #A09F9F;
border-left: 1px solid #B5B3B3;
border-right: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;
}

.remove{
background-color:#C4C3C2;
z-index:50;
position:absolute;
border-radius:5px;
moz-border-radius:5px;
border-top: 1px solid #A09F9F;
border-left: 1px solid #B5B3B3;
border-right: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;
}

.menu ul li a.contact{
background-image:none;
padding:0px 30px 0px 23px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:6px;
}
```

Jquery code:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var manageWidth = 14;
      var manageHeight = 10;
      var manageMargin = 6;

  $('.menu ul li a').hover(function(){

  var getHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
  var getWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
  $('<span class="mainhover" />').insertAfter($(this));
  $('.menu ul li .mainhover').css({'width':getWidth-manageWidth,'height':getHeight-manageHeight,'margin-top':'4px','margin-left':-getWidth+manageMargin ,'opacity':'0'});
  $('.menu ul li .mainhover').stop().animate({opacity:1},700);
  //alert(getWidth);
  },function(){
  $('.menu ul li a').next().removeClass('mainhover').addClass('remove').stop().animate({opacity:0},700,function(){
  $(this).remove();
});

});

    });
```

Comment: Seems Ok for me in FF on the Fiddle example. 16.0.2. What version are you using?

Comment: at a glance I'd check whitespace as a possible culprit

Comment: I´m curious... is there any reason why are you using this complex JS to achieve the effect you want? Because you want to spread them evenly? My first guess, the calculations are messing up your layout.

Comment: Yes I am trying to spread my span box evenly but I am not doing it well:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to don't use span, use div element to fix it.
Or you can try to add 'text-align:center;' to parent and 'text-align:left' to child.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the .menu ul has a width of 990px, just use 100%;

Comment: After changing this in the fiddle it seems to center perfectly for me

Comment: Basically the problem is the fixed width of the ul list and the padding of the anchors, not adding up.